# Does "before" make the Perfect Tense redundant?

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect

(Sorry for bothering you again with the Perfect Tense, I hope it ends soon.) I took a quiz and a grammar website said that I made a mistake.

Right sentence:

> When I **showed up** to take a look around, there were at least twenty other people who **had arrived** *before* me.

My sentence:

> When I **showed up** to take a look around, there were at least twenty other people who **arrived** *before* me.

In the second clause I used just `arrived` because I thought that the word `before` does all the job. Is it a real mistake? What sentence does sound better? Does “before” make the Perfect Tense redundant?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right that *before* with the past perfect makes it somewhat redundant. However, using the past perfect is the correct version of the sentence. The sentence is narrating the past and needs to describe a prior event, the exact purpose of the past perfect tense.

As StoneyB pointed out, the key to realizing that the past perfect is needed here is the *when* clause. The phrase *when I showed up* specifies a reference time in the past. In order to then talk about something which happened prior to that reference time the past perfect tense is necessary.

And about the redundancy, time adverbials (such as *before*) with past perfect can make it slightly redundant, but in a clarifying way. It's similar to specifying "positive 2" instead of just "2" as an answer on a math test, it becomes slightly redundant, but is more specific and clear.

So in summary, `past perfect + time adverbial` is a slightly redundant, but completely correct, grammar construction. And generally speaking, `past simple + time adverbial` is *not* a sufficient replacement for the past perfect tense.

Comment: Yes. The *when* clause pins down a Reference Time to which other times in the sentence must be related.

Comment: @StoneyB : Thank you for pointing this out, later today I will edit to add this as the reason that the past perfect is needed here.